# TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

Tags: python-2.7, reverse-engineering

I'm installing the radare2 python module and it gives me an error in the installation:

TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found

Comment: Please post full traceback

Comment: Please share the full error. Which r2 version did you install? Where did you downloaded r2pipe from?

Comment: That is the complete error that comes out in the cmd. The version is r2pipe 0.9.8 and the download site is https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=radare2+&submit=search